# Google Sheets Apps Script getting DNS error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Sheets and would like to hit my local MYSQL database via Apps Script.
I tried two methods, using JDBC and a call to a local API that I often use successfully from Javascript code.

JDBC:

```
  var server   = "localhost";
  var port     = "3306";
  var dbName   = "dictionary";
  var username = "xxxxxx";
  var password = "xxxxxx";
  var url      = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName;

  function readData() {
   console.log(url, username, password)
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

ERROR:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dictionary xxxxxx xxxxxx
12:26:37 PM   Error     Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

I then tried calling my local API:
Calling successfully from Javasctipt:

```
    let response = await fetch(url, {
                                     method:"POST",
                                     headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                     body:JSON.stringify({sqlline:this.sqlline})
                                    }
                              )
```

Calling from Apps Script:

```
    function apiTEST() {
      let url = 'http://localhost:4000/wordle/read';
      let sqlline = 'select word from dictionary.gamewords;'
      all_data = ""
    
      var options = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'header': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      'payload' : JSON.stringify({sqlline:sqlline})
      };
    
      console.log("URL:", url, "OPTIONS:", options);
    
      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    
      console.log("RESPONSE:", response)
      if (response.ok) {
         all_data =  response.json()
         console.log("Response JSON")
         console.log("ALL_DATA: ",all_data)
       }
       else {
         console.log("HTTP-Error:", response.status)
       }
      return
      }
```

The following error is raised:
Exception: DNS error: http://localhost:4000/wordle/read

I am guessing maybe since I am calling the API from a Google product, perhaps I need to grant a permission somewhere?  Just a guess.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found multiple posts saying my issue is the script is running on Google servers that are trying to hit my local machine.

Since I am not willing to open up access to my PC, I will attack my problem by generating the spreadsheet from Python or Javascript.